# Fast storage format for huge point clouds (fast read/write)

Tags: file-structure, big-data, file-formats

I am working with huge point clouds (1 billion points). I need to process and display them but because of the size of the data, I can't have it all in memory at the same time.

First of all, I am not asking for a tech that does that (CloudCompare, Potree, Terrasolid, etc.). I'm asking about a file format solution to this storage problem.

I plan on storing the point clouds in an octree with multi-resolution versions of the point cloud.
Each node contains a "section" of the point cloud(s) at a given resolution. Each node should be able to contain multiple point clouds (preferably separated so I can load one without having to load the others). Each point clouds is composed of points which can have attributes (at least x, y, z, t, g, b but in the future I'll add some so it must be flexible enough to allow that).

I'll be displaying the point clouds, so I need a very fast access to the node (as in, I don't want to parse 10GB of file before I find the node I asked for). And I'll be processing and modifying the data, so I need to b able to grow the nodes, modify the data. Even in the "middle" of the file, which means that it must support some kind of paging/chunking of the data to allow fast insertions.

The file format is not meant to be sharable between computer. It will just act as a cache while the program is running and the performances in read & write access are the most important.

Right now I've found some "solutions" :

- **completely custom** file format: I takes conception & development time, I may be reinventing the wheel but it will do what I want
- **directory structure** : I use the file system to do the work for me. I define the octree structure using directories and I store each of my point clouds as a file in the directories. Since each node is a small subset of the original point cloud (maybe 10k points), the writes won't take long, but to load a node, I need to read all the files in the directory which is not efficient. If I merge all the point clouds in a single file in each node, then it is not efficient to write to it if I want to modify a single point cloud
- **HDF5 based format** : Looks promising, I can store my whole octree in a single file, the lib handles for me all the chunking, fast access and management of the data, but I've heard some [bad things](http://cyrille.rossant.net/moving-away-hdf5/) about it (only one implementation which is hard to understand, complicated specifications). It may be overkill for my needs.
- **database** : Something like the pgPointCloud module for PostgreSGL.

The softwares I talked about earlier are :

- **potree** : uses a directory representation of the octree then store each node in a LAS or LAZ file. LAS/LAZ files are good for storing the data but not really to work on it (process & modification).
- **Terrasolid** : uses FBI (Fast Binary Format) files. I have trouble finding information on this file format but its name sounds promising. I don't think it is open but if you have resources on this format, that would be great.

I would prefer sticking with the octree structure (which has many advantages for me), but if an already existing format for storing spatially ordered data does what I need, feel free to mention it!

At the moment I'm leaning toward the HDF5 solution, but before I try running real tests, I'd like to have your opinion on the question.
Did I missed some solutions ? Are some solutions inefficient for my needs (like maybe the database solution ?). Do you have any experience on the subject that could help me ?

Thanks in advance !

(I posted here but maybe is there a more appropriate stackexchange forum dedicated to storage ? Sorry if I posted in the wrong place).

Comment: While you've given a lot of detail in this post, it essentially asks for a software recommendation, which is out of scope for this site as it mostly leads to answers that say "I've used X and it worked for me."

Comment: Based on the way that you've presented the question, however, I think that a pre-built solution would probably be best for you. I would personally look at the `pgPointCloud` module -- I took a quick look at it just now and it seems to be a high-quality project, which would leverage the other features of a DBMS.

Comment: Think of how modern map software use "zoom level tiling" to present pixels of entire surface of earth. The storage format is based on "view position".

Comment: @kdgregory > Where should I post this then to have answers ? I'll try pgPointCloud yes, the question was more to have other ideas that I would have missed.

Comment: @S.D. > the question was more on how to store the data for fast access and not how to format my data in a rendering optimized way.

Comment: @Ebatsin: dumb question: are the data points "roughly" uniformly spread or a very skewed distribution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in the field, nor do I know your exact constraints/data, but I *may* have an idea. Or at least something that would be worth trying *if the points are spread more or less uniformely*.

Instead of octree, there exists a simpler concept called "spatial hashing".
Basically, using your `x,y,z`, you compute an approximation of its location by rounding it and use it as a hash.

Basically, instead of a recusrsive octree you have a huge hash map filled with points. You just have to pick a coordinate rounding that fits well. *This technique is however not appropriate if the point distribution is very skewed.*

Persistent maps are easier to find than octree implementations. (Shameless self-promotion: if you're using python you can try mine if you want to give this a quick shot, it should be pretty efficient https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos). Of course, if performance is crucial, a tailored implementation would be fastest.

I also advise against using the filesystem to build huge octrees, it'll kill performance. Some DBs on the other hand have support for spatial indexes, that would probably be a good option too.